How to count the frequency of change of an attribute in any column in Sas
I have a dataset which has 100 columns. A simpler & smaller version is as follows:



As_of_Date
Account
Account_Number
Request_Type
Stage
Amount
Anticipated_Close_Date
Need_by_Date
Date_Accepted
Date_Confirmed




01-01-2024
John
ABC012345
New_Loan
Early
1000
02-28-2024





01-20-2024
John
ABC012345
New_Loan
Pending Acceptance
1500
02-28-2024
02-28-2024




01-20-2024
John
ABC345678
Existing_Loan
Early
2000
02-28-2024





02-03-2024
John
ABC012345
Existing_Loan
Confirmed
1500
02-28-2024
02-28-2024
02-10-2024
02-20-2024


02-23-2024
John
ABC345678
Existing_Loan
Confirmed
2000
02-28-2024
03-10-2024
02-25-2024
02-25-2024


01-01-2024
Sam
ABC135790
New_Loan
Pending Acceptance
500
01-10-2024
01-10-2024

01-05-2024


01-02-2024
Sam
ABC135790
New_Loan
Confirmed
500
01-10-2024
01-10-2024
01-03-2024
01-05-2024


02-10-2024
Peter
ABC246810
New_Loan
Pending Acceptance
1000
03-01-2024
03-01-2024




02-15-2024
Peter
ABC246810
Exisitng_Loan
Confirmed
1000
03-01-2024
03-07-2024
02-12-2024
02-15-2024


02-20-2024
Peter
ABC246810
Exisitng_Loan
Confirmed
2000
03-01-2024
03-10-2024
02-18-2024
02-19-2024



The dataset is unique at the 'As_of_Date' and 'Account_Number'. Except for the first 3 columns, any cell of any column can change. I need to find out the number of times the content of a column changes for each Account Number.
I know:
proc sort data = database; by Account_Number Account As_of_Date; run;

data want;
set database;
format lag_value mmddyy10.;
by Account_Number;
lag_vlaue = lag(Anticipated_close_date);
if first.Account_Number then value_change= 0;
else value_change = (Anticipated_close_date^=lag_value);
run;

is giving me the desired result. I need to do it for all the columns so I have done this:
proc contents data = database out=contents noprint; run;

proc sql;
select cats('_',varnum), cats(quote(trim(name),"'"),'N')
into
  :temp_column_vars separated by ' '
  :column_vars separated by ' '
from contents
where (name like '%Date%' and name ne 'As_of_Date');
quit;

proc sort data = database; by Account_Number Account As_of_Date; run;

data final;
set database;
by Account_Number;
array column &column_vars;
array temp_column &temp_column_vars;
do over column;
    lag_vlaue_&temp_column. = lag(&temp_column);
    if first.Account_Number then value_change_&temp_column.= 0;
    else value_change_&temp_column. = (&temp_column^=lag_value_&temp_column.);
end;
run;    

I get an error saying "Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order". Moreover, if I try to add 'Request_Type', 'Stage' etc in the array I get an error saying "All variables in array list must be the same type, i.e. all numeric or character."

You con only make an array of like type. (char or num). You seem to have mixed types.  If two variables in the same observation change does that count as one or two changes?  Or do you want to count both ways?

@Tom - I plan to run this process twice for the array issue. I was just asking if anyone has a workaround. If two variables in the same observation change, they should be counted as two. So, we need to create a separate column for each existing one and then count the respective changes. The final goal is to see which column is the most volatile, i.e. changes the most. This whole situation is a process flaw(as the dates keep on changing) that we are trying to analyze and improve.

Would counting the number of distinct values of a variable be enough?  Or do you really need to count every change?  e.g. 3-5-3-5 is three changes but only two distinct values.

This bit:  lag_vlaue_&temp_column. = lag(&temp_column); is probably a mistake.  When you use a single call the the LAG function, you will only have one queue for the lagging. Typically you would want a separate queue for each variable being lagged.

@Quentin- I need to count every change. Yeah,  lag_vlaue_&temp_column. = lag(&temp_column); is where I am getting the error. Any idea how to overcome this? Any other method is also fine.

You can track the account, variable name, and delta_count in a hash.
Example:
General purpose program to count number of changes in all variables within a by group.
data have;
    input As_of_Date :mmddyy10. Account $ Account_Number $ Request_Type $ Stage $ Amount Anticipated_Close_Date :mmddyy10. Need_by_Date :mmddyy10. Date_Accepted :mmddyy10. Date_Confirmed :mmddyy10.;
    format As_of_Date mmddyy10. Anticipated_Close_Date mmddyy10. Need_by_Date mmddyy10. Date_Accepted mmddyy10. Date_Confirmed mmddyy10.;
    datalines;
01-01-2024 John ABC012345 New_Loan Early 1000 02-28-2024 . . .
01-20-2024 John ABC012345 New_Loan Pending_Acceptance 1500 02-28-2024 02-28-2024 . .
01-20-2024 John ABC345678 Existing_Loan Early 2000 02-28-2024 . . .
02-03-2024 John ABC012345 Existing_Loan Confirmed 1500 02-28-2024 02-28-2024 02-10-2024 02-20-2024
02-23-2024 John ABC345678 Existing_Loan Confirmed 2000 02-28-2024 03-10-2024 02-25-2024 02-25-2024
01-01-2024 Sam ABC135790 New_Loan Pending_Acceptance 500 01-10-2024 01-10-2024 . 01-05-2024
01-02-2024 Sam ABC135790 New_Loan Confirmed 500 01-10-2024 01-10-2024 01-03-2024 01-05-2024
02-10-2024 Peter ABC246810 New_Loan Pending_Acceptance 1000 03-01-2024 03-01-2024 . .
02-15-2024 Peter ABC246810 Existing_Loan Confirmed 1000 03-01-2024 03-07-2024 02-12-2024 02-15-2024
02-20-2024 Peter ABC246810 Existing_Loan Confirmed 2000 03-01-2024 03-10-2024 02-18-2024 02-19-2024
;
run;

proc contents noprint data=have out=have_c;

proc sql noprint ;
  select 
    ifc(type=1, cats('_',put(varnum,z6.)) || ' ' || cats(length), '')
  , ifc(type=2, cats('_',put(varnum,z6.)) || ' $' || cats(length), '')
  into
    :num_vars separated by ' '
  , :char_vars separated by ' '
  from
    have_c
 order
    varnum
 ;

proc sort data=have;
  by account as_of_date ;
run ;

data _null_ ;
  set have end=end ;
  by account ;

  retain _nsentinel . _csentinel '' ;

  array nums _numeric_ ;    
  array chars _character_ ;

  length _nsentinel2 8  &num_vars _nsentinel3 8 ;
  length _csentinel2 $1 &char_vars _csentinel3 $1 ;

  array nprev _nsentinel2 -- _nsentinel3 ;
  array cprev _csentinel2 -- _csentinel3 ;
  retain _nsentinel2 -- _nsentinel3 _csentinel2 -- _csentinel3 ;

  length name vorder $32 delta_count 8 ;
  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    declare hash deltas (ordered:'a');
    deltas.defineKey ('account', 'vorder') ;
    deltas.defineData ('account', 'name', 'delta_count') ;
    deltas.defineDone() ;
    declare hiter hi ('deltas');
  end ;

  if not first.account then do ;
    do over nums ;
      if nums ne nprev[_i_+1] then do ;
        name = vname(nums) ;
        vorder = vname(nprev[_i_+1]) ;

        if deltas.find() ne 0 
          then delta_count = 1 ;
          else delta_count + 1 ;
        deltas.replace() ;
      end ;
    end ;
    do over chars ;
      if chars ne cprev[_i_+1] then do ;
        name = vname(chars) ;
        vorder = vname(cprev[_i_+1]) ;
        if deltas.find() ne 0 
          then delta_count = 1 ;
          else delta_count + 1 ;
        deltas.replace() ;
      end ;
    end ;
  end ;

  do over nums ;  nprev[_i_+1] = nums ; end ;
  do over chars ; cprev[_i_+1] = chars ; end ;

  if last.account then call missing (of nprev(*), of cprev(*)) ;

  if end then deltas.output(dataset:'deltas') ;
run ;


This works! Thanks a lot. Just a small request, is there a way to not count instances when a null value is being updated but if there is case when there was a value which changed to null and then again back to some value, we count that(as 2)? @Richard

You could add two more arrays nprev2 and cprev2 that are based on elements named __{varnum} and some more complicated coding for the bookkeeping / ruleset for the state determination.  I might also try a new core that uses LAG and LAG2 comparisons.

This does the trick I think.
If you don't want the missing values in case of no change, replace the call missing.
data HAVE;
  As_of_Date=1; AC_NO=1; V1=1; V2='a'; V3=1; V4='b'; output;
  As_of_Date=2; AC_NO=1; V1=2; V2='a'; V3=1; V4='a'; output;
  As_of_Date=3; AC_NO=1; V1=2; V2='b'; V3=1; V4='a'; output;
  As_of_Date=4; AC_NO=1; V1=1; V2='c'; V3=2; V4='a'; output;
run;

data COUNT;
  set HAVE;
  by AC_NO;
  array N_VAR [2] 8  V1 V3;
  array C_VAR [2] $1 V2 V4;
  array N_CNT [2] 8 ;
  array C_CNT [2] 8 ; 

  do I=1 to dim(N_VAR);
    if lag(N_VAR[I]) ne N_VAR[I] then if ^first.AC_NO then N_CNT[I]+1;
  end;
  do I=1 to dim(C_VAR);
    if lag(C_VAR[I]) ne C_VAR[I] then if ^first.AC_NO then C_CNT[I]+1;
  end;
  if last.AC_NO then do;
    output;
    call missing (of N_CNT[*], of C_CNT[*]); 
  end;
run;
  

Just sum the N and the C changes for a total.
Result:
N_CNT1  N_CNT2  C_CNT1  C_CNT2
     2       1       2       1

